# PHP Comments script for a website not working

Tags: php, mongodb, web, html

I am learning web development from "PHP and MongoDB Web Development" book. I came across these instructions for creating a blog and adding comments into it.

**1)Open blog.php in your text editor and replace the existing code in it with the
following:**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
try {
$connection = new Mongo();
$database
= $connection->selectDB('myblogsite');
$collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
} catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}
$article = $collection->findOne(array('_id' =>
new MongoId($id)));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>My Blog Site</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contentarea">
<div id="innercontentarea">
<h1><?php echo $article['title']; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $article['content']; ?></p>
<div id="comment-section">
<h3>Comments</h3>
<?php if (!empty($article['comments'])): ?>
<h3>Comments</h3>
<?php foreach($article['comments'] as $comment):echo $comment['name'].' says...';?>
<p><?php echo $comment['comment']; ?></p>
<span>
<?php echo date('g:i a, F j', $comment['posted_at']->sec); ?>
</span><br/><br/><br/>
<?php endforeach;endif;?>
<h3>Post your comment</h3>
<form action="comment.php" method="post">
<span class="input-label">Name</span>
<input type="text" name="commenter_name" class="comment-input"/>
<br/><br/>
<span class="input-label">Email</span>
<input type="text" name="commenter_email" class="comment-input"/>
<br/><br/>
<textarea name="comment"vrows="5"></textarea><br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $article['_id']; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2) Create comment.php file with the following code:**

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['article_id'];
try {
$mongodb = new Mongo();
$collection = $mongodb->myblogsite->articles;
} catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
die('Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage());
}
$article = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => MongoId($id)));
$comment = array('name' => $_POST['commenter_name'],'email' => $_POST['commenter_email'],'comment' => $_POST['comment'],'posted_at' => new MongoDate());
$collection->update(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)),array('push' => array('comments' => $comments)));
header('Location: blogs.php?id='.$id);
?>
```

**3)Navigate to blogs.php in your browser, click on the Read More link of the top
article to read its full content in the blog.php page. The code for blogs.php is as follows:**

```
<?php
try {
$connection = new Mongo();
$database
= $connection->selectDB('myblogsite');
$collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
} catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}
$cursor = $collection->find();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>My Blog Site</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contentarea">
<div id="innercontentarea">
<h1>My Blogs</h1>
<?php while ($cursor->hasNext()):
$article = $cursor->getNext(); ?>
<h2><?php echo $article['title']; ?></h2>
<p>
<?php echo substr($article['content'], 0,
200).'...'; ?>
</p>
<a href="blog.php?id=<?php echo $article['_id'];
?>">Read more</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to post a comment it is redirecting to a blank page. How to make this code work?

Comment: Check the PHP logs for errors.  Turn on PHP error reporting if it's off.  A blank page often means there's some kind of error, but you need to find out what and where that error is.

Answer (score 0):

Above all code in comment.php put the following (just under the PHP opening tag):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

That will show you the error that's causing the blank page and will hopefully help you on your way.

Comment: These were the errors :
Deprecated: main(): The Mongo class is deprecated, please use the MongoClient class in /var/www/html/comment.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to undefined function MongoId() in /var/www/html/comment.php on line 11

I tried to fix them but failed. Can you help me?

Comment: I've never worked with Mongo myself but that makes it clear that the comment script you are using is outdated.

Comment: You could try changing $connection = new Mongo(); to $connection = new MongoClient(); Just a guess though